# Alert does not work on AJAX success

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have AJAX script that write data to table

Here is code

```
<script>
$('#save_appointment').click(function () {
    addAppointmentInternal();
});
function addAppointmentInternal() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            Start: $('#startAppointment').val(),
            End: $('#endAppointment').val(),
            Title: $('#title').val()
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("AddingInternalAppointment","Calendar")',
        sucess: function (da) {
            if (da.Result === "Success") {
                alert();
            } else {
                alert('Error' + da.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function(da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

And here is code on back-end

```
 public ActionResult AddingInternalAppointment(string Start, string End, string Title)
    {
        Appointment appointment = new Appointment()
        {
            Start_appointment = Start,
            End_appointment = End,
            Title = Title
        };
        db.Appointments.Add(appointment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully" });
    }
```

And all okay. Data is writing to table. But I have problem, on success I don't get alert message.

Where can be problem?

Comment: `===` is `==` in your javascript?

Comment: @Sybren - `===` is a valid equality operator in JavaScript.  As JavaScript is weakly-typed, the `==` is a weak-type equality comparison and `===` is strong-type equality.

Comment: try `console.log(da)` make sure you got thing correct and plaese show me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`success:` typo error in ajax success. You are using sucess. Check and correct it.

Change

```
sucess: function (da) {
```

To

```
success: function (da) {
```